# Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly. Python3.9.0

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I am trying to install openCV-python with command prompt and I am getting the error `Could not build wheels for opencv-python which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly.`

After trying every solution I could find I decided to ask here. I have tried the following:

1. Upgrading pip. Confirmed the update to 20.2.4
2. Clearing old versions of python. Only 3.9.0 is installed
3. I re-installed visual studio with the c++ tools since opencv needs them apparently
4. I tried installing opencv-python using both pip and pip3 same error for each
5. I tried installing cmake, wheels, numpy, and dklib all individually
6. I tried to install an older version of opencv using `pip install opencv-python==4.3.0.38`

Please help. I need this installed to start a new project working with ImageGrab